# Python Unicode escape error after using open()

Tags: python, file, pycharm, text-files

I am trying to open a text file 'Person.txt' and I get this error

This is my code:

```
PD = open('C:\Users\Scooter\PeopleList.txt')
```

This is the file:

```
a
b
c
d
```

This is the error:

```
C:\Users\Scooter\PycharmProjects\class.py\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Scooter/PycharmProjects/class.py/main.py
  File "C:\Users\Scooter\PycharmProjects\class.py\main.py", line 1
    PD = open('C:\Users\Scooter\PeopleList.txt')
                                               ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Comment: Try with "\\", instead of "\".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backslash `\` is the escape character, to use a literal backslash in a string you must escape it by using `\\`

```
PD = open('C:\\Users\\Scooter\\PeopleList.txt')
```

Or use a raw string to "disable" this escaping behaviour by prefixing the string with `r`

```
PD = open(r'C:\Users\Scooter\PeopleList.txt')
```